# Gluon Charm (invalid license key) - Example app run only in the desktop mode

Tags: java, javafxports, gluon-mobile

In the desktop it runs normally with the license key.
After run ./gradlew androidInstall when I open the app (in my LG G4) it crashes!!

I await for your replay,

Eder Maciel Martelo

Comment: There are multiple reasons that could explain why the application crashes. Can you run `./adb logcat -v threadtime` and post the stacktrace that reveals the exception?

Comment: As you requested I executed the command "adb logcat -d > logcat.txt" in the terminal for your analysis.
[ logcat.txt, exception part ]: "... Not granting permission android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS to package com.gluonhq.demo.gonative (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be46)V/BackupManagerService( 1268): restoreAtInstall pkg=com.gluonhq.demo.gonative token=a restoreSet=0V/BackupManagerService( 1268): Finishing install immediatelyI/ActivityManager( 1268): Start proc 16785:com.lge.appbox.client/u0a12 for broadcast com.lge.appbox.client/com.lge.appbox. ..."

Comment: You can edit your question, and post the relevant part of the stacktrace there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stacktrace:

> Not granting permission android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

reveals that you are not assigning the required permissions on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

By default, the plugin creates a manifest with this permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In case you require additional permissions or you want to remove them if they are not necessary, you just need to edit the file `/src/android/AndroidManifest.xml`, and modify it accordingly:

```
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

Finally, save, and deploy again.

Comment: It worked for me! Thank you very much!

Eder Maciel Martelo